# stored procedure with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem in an update and delete in `CodeIgniter` using store procedure. I have following code in model

```php
public function getuser($users_id)
{
    $get_user_stored_proc = "CALL get_user(?,?)";
    $query = $this->db->get_where($get_user_stored_proc, array('users_id' => $users_id));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function update_user($user, $users_id)
{
    $update_user_stored_proc = "CALL update_user(?,?)";
    $this->db->where($update_user_stored_proc, $users_id;
    return $this->db->update('users', $user);
}

public function delete_user($users_id)
{
    $delete_user_stored_proc = "CALL delete_user(?,?)";
    $result = $this->db->where($delete_user_stored_proc, $users_id);
    if ($result !== null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have following error:

[image]

Comment: Is there any error throwing?

Comment: Would you please share stored procedures so that we might be able to get clear picture. Thanks

Comment: /home/puskar/Pictures/Screenshot from 2019-02-20 09-09-00.png

Answer (score 0):

You are only giving a value to the store procedure when he expects two.
In the screenshot you provide we can see only a user id (6) on the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Delete user:
    **Controller page:**
    public function delete_user(){
            $uri_id=$this->uri->segment(4,0);
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('Home_model');
            $this->Home_model->delete_user($uri_id);
            redirect('controller_name/viewuserlist','refresh');
        }
    // uri_id is the id you send through the url of the page 
    **Model page:**
    function delete_user($user_id){
          $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
          return $this->db->delete('table_name');
        }
```